# Compute $\oint\frac{e^{2z}+\sin z}{(z^2+1)^3}dz$, over the curve C

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

> Compute $I = \oint\frac{e^{2z}+\sin z}{(z^2+1)^3}dz$, over the curve $C:|z+i|=r, r\neq2$

So what I understood from my classes I have to find what it's poles are and then apply the residual theorem but I have some problems when trying to determine in what interval $r$ is and use that..

So what I've done so far is:

$z^2+1=0\implies z_{1,2}=\pm i$ and then I have to check for what $r$ are these roots in the $IntC$, right?
Then apply the theorem that $I=2\pi i \sum_{z_k\space singular \space point}Rez(f(z), z_k)$

Say for $z_1\in IntC\implies |i+i|< r\leftrightarrow 2 < r$, but for $z_2\in IntC\implies |-i+i|< r\leftrightarrow 0 < r$, how do I deal with this?

And we have $\pm i$ poles of order $3$ for that polynomial.. how do I solve it from here? And how do I prove that the integral is $0$ if the singular points are not in the interior of the curve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities here:

1. $r<2$: In this case, the only residue that have have to deal with is the residue at $-i$. The residue theorem tells us then that the integral is equal to\begin{align}2\pi i\operatorname{res}_{z=-i}\left(\frac{e^{2z}+\sin z}{(z^2+1)^3}\right)&=\frac{2\pi i}{16}e^{-2 i}\left((6+i)-4 e^{2 i}\sinh1+3e^{2i}\cosh1\right)\\&=\frac{\pi i}8e^{-2 i}\left((6+i)-4 e^{2 i}\sinh1+3e^{2i}\cosh1\right).\end{align}
2. $r>2$: In this case, you will have also to deal with the residue at $i$. Since$$\operatorname{res}_{z=i}\left(\frac{e^{2z}+\sin z}{(z^2+1)^3}\right)=\frac1{16}\left((-6+i)e^{2 i}+4\sinh1-3\cosh1\right)$$the integral will be then equal to (after some manipulations):$$\frac\pi8\left(-\frac{7i}e+(1-6i)e^{-2 i}-(1+6i)e^{2i}+ie\right).$$

Note that the singularity $-i$ is always in the region bounded by the curve.

Comment: How did you get to the posibilities that $r < 2$ or $r > 2$ and why didn't you consider $r < 0, r > 0$?Radius of course can't be negative, and always has to be positive but what if there was another number a non-zero number such as if you just plugged in $z_1$ and $z_2$ into the curve relation you had something like that"?

Comment: If $r<0$, then the set $\{z\in\mathbb C\,|\,\lvert z+i\rvert=r\}$ is empty. Why should I care about it?

Comment: True, I understand, oh, forget that, why did you took the cases $r > 2$ or $r < 2$?

Comment: Because if $r=2$, then $-i$ belongs to the curve and therefore the integral doesn't make sense. So, only the case $r\in(0,2)$ and $r>2$ matter.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I think you meant to say that if $r=2$, then $i$ belongs to the curve.

Comment: Why if $i$ belongs to the curve the integral doesn't make sense?

Comment: Also how do I know on which poles to apply the residual theorem based on $r$?

Comment: If $i$ belongs to the curve, you shall be integrating un unbounded function, which is not defined at all the points of the curve.

Comment: If $r<2$, the only singularity in the region of $\mathbb C$ bounded by the curve is $-i$. Otherwise, there are two of them: $i$ and $-i$.

Comment: @PierreCarre I shall have to edit my answer.

Comment: @C.Cristi If the singularity is on the curve you can try to make a perturbed version of the curve depending on a small parameter $\varepsilon$ that puts the singularity inside the curve, use the residuals theorem to compute the integral (depends on $\varepsilon$) and then make $\varepsilon \to 0$. This is delicate.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos And you know this because $|z + i| $ is a circle centered at $-i$ and therefore $-i$ is always in it and if the radius gets bigger then it might include $i$ too, because the distance between $i$ and $-i$ is 2, so that's why you took those cases, but this is a simple case, what if the curve was a little more complicated? Also, why it doesn't work if $r = 2$?

Comment: @PierreCarre Oh, I see, it's with that little circle of radius $\epsilon$? How would you have done it?

Comment: By the way, one more question, IF I already calculated the residue of the function in $-i$ at the previous step do I have to calculate it again? No, right? Because it's still the residue of $f$ and $f$ is not changing

Comment: @C.Cristi Yes, it is with that little circle with radius $\varepsilon$, but please understand that I am not claiming that you can successfully use the technique  in this particular case. You would need to show that the integral on that "extra" arc is bounded by a function that tends to zero as $\varepsilon \to 0$.

Comment: @PierreCarre I've finally edited the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track...

If $r < 2$ the only pole in the interior of $C$ is $z=i$ and the integral is given by

$$
\int_C f(z) dz = 2\pi i Res(f,-i)
$$
If $r > 2$ there are two poles inside the curve and the integral is given by

$$
\int_C f(z) dz = 2 \pi i (Res(f,-i) + Res (f,i))
$$

Comment: My actual question is, how did you get that $r < 2$ or $r > 2$?

Comment: Well, $r=2$ is a special case because the pole would be on the curve and the residue theorem would not be directly applicable. Leaving out $r=2$, the possibilities are $0 < r<2$ or $r>2$